# How do I capture the running vm directory using sed?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, sed

I have this command to print out all the info of a running vm. What I really need is just the directory that the vm is running.

Here's what I have got so far.

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | grep vip-quickstart | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | xargs VBoxManage showvminfo | sed '/\'srv\', Host path: (.*)\'$/p'
```

And this is the output

```
Name: 'srv', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart' (machine mapping), writable
Name: 'srv_www_wp-content_themes_vip', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/theme' (machine mapping), writable
Name: 'project', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/' (machine mapping), writable
Name: 'tmp_vagrant-puppet_manifests-846018e2aa141a5eb79a64b4015fc5f3', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart/puppet/manifests' (machine mapping), writable
Name: 'tmp_vagrant-puppet_modules-c332b5484a483ddd4cb97b359aa0eb4f', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart/puppet/modules' (machine mapping), writable
```

But what I want is just `/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart` from this line

```
Name: 'srv', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart' (machine mapping), writable
```

Comment: As an aside, `grep 'foo' | awk '{ bar }'` is basically always [better](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) written as `awk '/foo/ { bar }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last `sed` to:

```
sed -n "/'srv', Host path: /p"
```

`-n` will suppress all other lines except the one matching with this pattern.

**EDIT:** To print just the matched directory path use:

```
sed -nr "s/.*'srv', Host path: '([^']+)'.*/\1/p"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer what about if I want to grab just the directory?

Comment: I tried this and didn't work `sed -n "/'srv', Host path: (.*)\1/"`

Comment: Then you can use: **`sed -nr "s/.*'srv', Host path: '([^']+)'.*/\1/p" file`**